# PDFsharp/MigraDoc FootNote usage

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm generating a c# project and I want to add some footnotes to my PDF file. I want to create footnotes which present additional documents on it.

I tried these but none of these are working; nothing shows up on my PDF file.

```
Paragraph paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
FootNote fn = paragraph.AddFootnote();
fn.AddParagraph("¹You should add document one.");

-------------------------------------

paragraph.AddFootnote("¹You should add document one.");
```

I didn't find what is wrong,

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Footnotes do not work with the current implementation of MigraDoc.

Answer (score 0):

A small workaround. This solution is far from perfect but should work.

First Mark the text with your pseudo footnote mark:

```
Paragraph p = section.AddParagraph("");
p.AddText("Now comes the text with the footnote"); // the text itself

Font f = p.Format.Font.Clone();
f.Superscript = true;        
p.AddFormattedText("1", f); // your pseudo footnote, just a superscripted mark
```

Then put the footnote explanation below on your page like:

```
Paragraph pFootnote = section.AddParagraph("");
pFootnote.AddText("________"); pFootnote.AddLineBreak();
Font fFootnote = pFootnote.Format.Font.Clone();
fFootnote.Superscript = true;
pFootnote.AddFormattedText("1", fFootnote); // footnote itself
pFootnote.AddText(" footnote explanation");
```